# Deselect row in Table UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a Table with MultiToggle.

I want to check if it is  in a range and if not I want to deselect this row before I book the others. 
How it is possible?

With `oTable.setSelectedIndex()` I can just select one row but I want to select / deselect more than one.

Comment: for loop can help in this case I guess!

Comment: Yes but how can i deselect one row Example I have 1 2 4 6 selected and I want just 126 selected

Answer (score 1):

For sap.ui.table.Table, use `clearSelection()` method.

For sap.m.Table, use `removeSelections(true)` method.

Answer (score 0):

To deselect one or more rows you could use `removeSelectionInterval`.

If you don't necessarily need `sap.ui.table.Table` you might switch to `sap.m.Table`. There you have the method `setSelectedItem(oListItem, bSelect)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use setSelectionMode(). This will remove all the selected table items in sap.ui.table.